# Making new VPN credentials

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, login, windows-server-2003

I have a question about VPN connection login credentials. I am just starting to work at a new job, and am not very familiar with server side, and IT type problems (I am a programmer). I am not able to contact the old IT employee.

So what my question is, is:

I am connecting to the companies network via VPN with my boss' VPN credentials. But I need to set up an account to be able to connect via VPN also. The computer he will be using is running on Windows XP business. And the Server is running windows server 2003.

So what I am thinking is I need to go into the server and make the user account 'Steve' have privileges to connect via VPN.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the right thing to do, what happened when you tried?  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: Well I am able to log on with an administrative account 'roger'. But I want to be able to make the 'Steve' account able to log onto the VPN. And when I am mapping drives, use Steve's account to do so.

Comment: OK, and as you say, you need to create an account on the server and give them VPN access.  Have you done that?  Where are you getting stuck while doing that?

Comment: Well, I am not very familiar with that. So I went onto the server computer, and added 'Steve' to the group that from what I understand gives the privileges. But when I go to log into the VPN connection with his username it does not work.